# Generating default Material in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script to store information about a material that will be retrieved by another script. If a material is not given, a default material will be applied. The only special thing
about this material is that the Smoothness is zero, as this characteristic is fixed I decided to leave this material to be created via code so as not to pollute the folder with the rest of the materials.

For this, I write this code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class Slicerable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Material DefaultMaterial;
    [Tooltip("The material asigned to the new triangles created by the planes intersection")]
    [field: SerializeField]
    Material CuttingMaterial { get; private set; }
    public bool isCopy { get; private set; }

    void Awake()
    {
        if (DefaultMaterial is not null)
        return;
        DefaultMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture"))
        {
            color = Color.gray
        };
        DefaultMaterial.SetInt("_Smoothness", 0);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        CuttingMaterial = CuttingMaterial ?? DefaultMaterial;
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to model this scenario? I mean, there is some way better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"best" is what works best for you ;)

Alternatively you could create an actual asset and assign it as default reference via the Inspector of the script itself so the field will be pre-populated - but only in the editor.

So if this is supposed to rather be some sort of fallback for runtime it's probably better to runtime create it yes. I would probably do it via

```
public static Material DefaultMaterial;

[RuntimeInitializeOnLoad(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.SubsystemRegistration)]
private static void Initialize()
{
    if(DefaultMaterial) return;

    DefaultMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture"))
    {
        color = Color.gray
    };
    DefaultMaterial.SetInt("_Smoothness", 0);
}
```